# How to parse Json data which is in the HTTP post request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance

Here is the **Json** Data:

```
filterKeys":{"${FilterGroup}":["Phenols"]},"lastFilterGroup":"${FilterGroup}"}
```

I have to extract `phenols` from the post request for every filter group this value changes.

Comment: Do you mean a response? If you have a request why would you need to parse anything from it?

Comment: I am aware of using regular expression for extracting response value in the Response data but I am not sure how to use Regular expression for the json data which is in the POST request.

Comment: How do you compose your POST request? JSON data should somehow get to the request body. How does it get there?

Comment: This is my Body data in the jmeter which is in the Json format {"keyword":"${Keyword}","maxlength":25,"offset":0,"sortKeys":{"ascending":false,"attributeName":"relevance","type":"ATTRIBUTE"},"filterKeys":{"analyte":["Phenols"]},"lastFilterGroup":"analyte"} so this is my request. Based on the selection of filter groups (in this case analyte) the term Phenols changes everytime and I want to extract that value to a regular expression variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since request payloads have to be composed by yourself, it doesn't make much sense to extract data from there.
Makes sense, instead, to fill them with data you take/populate from somewhere.

What could easily be done then, is to populate the request body with variables, so your **request** body may look like this:

```
{  
   "keyword":"${Keyword}",
   "maxlength":25,
   "offset":0,
   "sortKeys":{  
      "ascending":false,
      "attributeName":"relevance",
      "type":"ATTRIBUTE"
   },
   "filterKeys":{  
      "${filter_key}":[  
         "${filter_value}"
      ]
   },
   "lastFilterGroup":"${filter_key}"
}
```

And add a **[JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)** (using groovy) to that request sampler, where to put values for those variables, like:

```
vars.put('filter_key', 'analyte');
vars.put('filter_value', 'Phenols');
```

Otherwise, if you want to extract "*analyte*" and "*Phenol*" from that JSON body, given it is a response, you can add a **[JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)** to the sampler and use the following path expressions

```
$.filterKeys
```

to get

```
[
  {
    "analyte": [
      "Phenols"
    ]
  }
]
```

and

```
$.filterKeys.analyte.*
// or
$.filterKeys.${filter_key}.*
```

to get

```
[
  "Phenols"
]
```

or other combinations that you can try out on several websites like [this](http://jsonpath.com/).